# How to check existing data with jquery validation library with codeigniter 4 when csrf is set to auto?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form that I'm trying to validate with jquery validation plugin and codeigniter 4, I have enabled csrf that set to auto generate for every request. I'm able get validation status on first request but when I try another request I get error 403, and when I set second param to json_encode() I get error 500. I want to be able to update csrf after each request on ajax call.

//My router

```
  $routes->post('check-category', 'Admin\Category::check_category');
```

//my controller

```
//check if category name exist
    public function check_category()
    {
        $name = $this->request->getPost('name');
        $query = $this->db->table('categories')
                          ->where(['cat_name' => $name])
                          ->get()
                          ->getResult();
        
        $status = true;
        if(count($query) > 1){
            $status = false;
        }else{
            $status = true;
        }
        $data['csrf'] = csrf_hash();
        echo json_encode($status, $data);
    }
```

// javascript

```
    $('#create_category').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            name: {
                remote: {
                    url: 'check-category',
                    type: "post",
                    data:{
                        csrf_hash_name: function(){
                           return $('input[name="csrf_hash_name"]').val();
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function(data){
                       $('input[name="csrf_hash_name"]').val(data.csrf);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {remote: "This category exists."}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { return false; }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much struggle I finally found the solution of my problem. Now I'm able to update csrf token with the dataFilter object and get rid off error 403 during ajax call.
Here is what I have done to my controller even I broked Mvc principle by getting data from db direct to the controller.
I know it could not the best way for what I have done, Please correct me if any suggestion I'll appreciate. Thanks!

//my controller method

```
    public function check_category()
    {
        $name = $this->request->getPost('name');
        $query = $this->db->table('categories')->where(['cat_name' => $name])->countAllResults();
        
        $valid = true;
        if($query > 0){
            $valid = false;
        }else{
            $valid = true;
        }
        $csrf = csrf_hash();
        return $this->response->setJSON(['valid'=>$valid, 'csrf'=>$csrf]);
    }
```

// my javascript

```
    $('#create_category').validate({
          onkeyup: false,
          rules: {
              name: {
                  required: true,
                  remote: {
                      url: 'check-category',
                      type: 'post',
                      dataType:'json',
                      dataFilter: function(data){
                          let obj = eval('('+data+')');
                          $('input[name="csrf_hash_name"]').val(obj.csrf);
                          return obj.valid;
                      },
                      data:{ csrf_hash_name: function(){ return $('input[name="csrf_hash_name"]').val(); } }
                  }
              }
          },
          messages: {
              name: {
                  required: "Enter a Category.",
                  remote: "{0} This category exists."
              }
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
              return false;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

the structure of the php function [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) looks like this:

```
json_encode ( mixed $value , int $flags = 0 , int $depth = 512 ) : string|false
```

and returns:

> a string containing the JSON representation of the supplied value.

in your controller function `check_category()` you are sending `$status`, while `$data` is setting an invalid flag:

```
echo json_encode($status, $data);  // wrong
```

change `$status = true;` into `$data['status'] = true`;

and just echo both, status and the csrf hash

```
echo json_encode($data);  // correct
```

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it but my problem now is how do I get that response data to the remote data object " remote:{ data: { } } "?